# How to check array and add new cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare elements with isnt cookies.
For that I made script (only for use by console) - it is working but is checking only one - first cookie and add second. When I have for example 2 cookies - test1, test2 it's not working. In what way I can change it?

```
var arrMy = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];
var i = 0;
function nextItem() {
    i = i + 1; /
    i = i % arrMy.length;
    return arrMy[i];
}
var x = nextItem();
console.log(x);

for(document.cookie.indexOf(x) > -1 == true;;){
function nextItem2() {
    i = i + 1;
    i = i % arrMy.length; 
    return arrMy[i];
}

var w = nextItem2();
if(x != w){
break;
}
}
document.cookie =  w+'=yet another test; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2021 02:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 functions that do the same thing?

Comment: If selected element from the array is a existing cookie I want to select next element from the array and That If that element is different from first result then make next cookie ... Something like that, it hard to explain for me a litle bit cause I'm newbie in js

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the cookies:
var cookies=document.cookie.split(";");
//cookies to add
var add=["test=1","test=2"]
//loop trough the cookies to add
add.forEach(cookie=>{
       //if the cookie isnt found
       if(!cookies.find(el=>el.split("=")[0]===cookie.split("=")[0])){
            //add the cookie
           cookies.push(cookie);       
        }
});
document.cookie=cookies.join(";");
```